# Angular need to decode url to display on page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

My console.log from angular 5 service call to component correctly shows the correct data URL

```
http://localhost:4200/inquiry?UserID=645
```

However, when it is in the angular for loop in html template it shows

```
http://localhost:4200/inquiry%3FUserID%3D645
```

Am the minimum i really need the `?` to be there for my routing

Trying to find URL decoding, how do i accomplish this in component typescript or in template html ngfor loop ?  with a pipe ?

Comment: how do you use this url? are you just showing it in the frontend or are you trying to use it to call your backend in an http request? Is this a link for a backend request or is it a link for Angular routing to get to another component?

Comment: its in a menu system that if clicked navigate     localhost will become server

Comment: By navigate you mean route? Like jumping from one view to another but inside the app? Or to somewhere else, seperated fron your current angular app?

Comment: console.log of the data correctly shows the `?`  but when angular renders output in html in my menu instead it is a `%3F`

Answer (score 1):

via template only:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users" routerLink="/inquiry" [queryParams]="{ UserID: user.id }">user.name</div>
```

template and component:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users" (click)="navigateTo(user.id)">user.name</div>

navigateTo(id: number) {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('http://localhost:4200/inquiry?UserID='+id);
}
```